# Will enabling WSL and Virtual Machine Platform for running WSL2 slow down the host OS?

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I wish to know if enabling WSL and Virtual Machine Platform for running WSL2 would slow down the host OS.

I am not entirely sure what kind of virtualization WSL uses (the kind where both host and guest run on a hypervisor or the one in which the host runs the hypervisor within it, with the guest running over it).
So will enabling WSL have any performance impact over the host os when no guest os is running, and also will it have any impact on the overall battery life of a laptop?

Comment: Running any application on a laptop will impact battery life.  WSL2 uses Hyper-V which is a Type-2 hypervisor (i.e. a hypervisor that runs within an OS).  A Type-1 hypervisor is more often described as a bare-metal hypervisor (i.e. ESXi or Hyper-V Server).  if the WSL2 instance is not actually running, like all software, would not impact battery life.

Comment: WSL (1 or 2) is only running when you run it, by starting a terminal. If you close it, the WSL2 system will shut down soon after or you can do `wsl --shutdown` from a Windows CMD prompt.

Comment: Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor, not a type 2, regardless of client or server.  Even though it seems like a type 2 due to Windows running, Hyper-V runs below Windows and places Windows in the "primary partition" which is essentially a special VM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would upgrading to Windows 10 Pro and enabling WSL affect my laptop's performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/1378879/would-upgrading-to-windows-10-pro-and-enabling-wsl-affect-my-laptops-performanc).  I know that was originally written back before WSL2 even existed, but I added an [answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1748740/1210833) about the Virtual Machine Platform not too long ago.  In general, I'm hoping that will answer your question.  Thanks!